# Why is it preferred to use $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ instead of $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$

Tags: measure-theory, notation, definition

I am curious why a in measure theory often the notation $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ is preferred to $(A_n)_n$.

For example we can say a measure space $(A,B,\mu)$ is sigma finite if there exist a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of measurable sets with finite measure with $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=A$.

On the other hand one can say $(A,B,\mu)$ is sigma finite if there are at most countably many sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots \in B$ with $\mu(A_n)<\infty $ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ that satisfy $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=A$.

I guess both definitions ar equivalent, but the latter is often preferred. Why?

Comment: What makes you think it is preferred?

Comment: there is not generally "preferred notation". The notation just depends on the writer and what he likes more. Maybe you were reading some textbook where the author uses this notation, this is all

Comment: "is often preferred." That would need some evidence, but if it is true, then I'd guess the reason is just that $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a slightly more complicated notation, when what is being considered is a simple thing.

Comment: so what notation would you suggest me to use to be precise, the latter or is it absolutely irrelevant?

Comment: @RogerSweet You're free to use the one that pleases you most. There is obviously no difference between those two.

Comment: By my reckoning "let $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subseteq B$" requires 41 keystrokes, while "let $A_1, A_2,\ldots \in B$" requires a mere 26. Math authors are nothing if not efficient.

Comment: Minor additional comment: There is sometimes ambiguity about whether or not $\mathbb{N}$ includes 0.

Comment: @Michael Indeed, though, in this context, it makes no difference.  The point is that a space is $\sigma$-finite if it can be written as the union of countably many measurable sets of finite measure.  The indexing of that countable collection is hardly relevant.

Comment: From my own personal experience taking measure theory and having taken a number of math classes, sometimes I think there is no valid and logical reason for everything we do. Sure, when we prove something of course we are going to make the proof logically air-tight and rigorous--that's the job of a mathematician--but for things like this, it just comes down to convention and personal preference.

Comment: Thinking as a teacher I feel that the notation $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ has a greater didactic value for beginners than the other. On the other hand I don't think it is preferred ( in a vast sense by the authors.